# neo4jclient poor performance when creating a single node

Tags: c#, .net-core, neo4jclient

It's taking around 2s to create a simple node using Neo4jClient accessing a local Neo4j testing database.

I have a Neo4j 3.5.12 server running locally on my machine for dev purposes, connecting to it through the awesome Neo4jClient .NET on ASP.NET Core (.NET Core 3).

As recommended in the Neo4jClient docs, the Microsoft DI configuration:

```
public static void AddNeo4jClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<NeoServerConfiguration>(serviceProvider =>
    {
        var settings = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<Neo4jSettings>>().Value;
        return NeoServerConfiguration.GetConfiguration(settings.Url, settings.Username, settings.Password);
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IGraphClientFactory, GraphClientFactory>();
}
```

I inject IGraphClientFactory into my service and use as follows:

```
public async Task CreateUser(User user)
{
    using var client = _factory.Create();

    await client.Cypher
        .Create($"(n:{ NodeTypes.USER }) SET n = $newNode")
        .WithParam("newNode", user)
        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
}
```

When I step over the await statement, it takes around 2s. This doesn't seem to be a warm-up issue as the same delay happens when calling the function again. I'm under the impression that since the NeoServerConfiguration is registered as a singleton, the overhead of URL discovery is only done once and hence I should be able to create new IGraphClients in a transient fashion.

Have I miss-configured something?

Comment: Are you creating a `GraphClient` instance everytime you run this? What is the `GraphClientFactory`? You should have **1** instance of `IGraphClient` per your session - you definitely should not be creating a new GraphClient instance each time

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think I need to go for a singleton for IGraphClient. The docs https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting under "Threading and Lifestyles" states that "You can use single neo server configuration object and use graph client per request instead of singleton" by using IGraphClientFactory - I was hoping to get this working.

Comment: I've never done that and I don't know why you would - the docs aren't gated, so I'm not sure why that's there - everytime you create a graphclient - you end up having to do connect which is your time addition

Comment: It's mainly a belt and braces approach: "This may be beneficial for hi-transaction environments where concurrent transaction exception may occur". As I understand it, since the settings (NeoServerConfiguration) are already fetched into a singleton, URL discovery is not required for every instance of GraphClient making its instantiation lightweight. I must be misinterpreting something or there is some bug. For the record, I switched to a IGraphClient as a singleton and the performance is great. I'll stick with this for now.

Comment: I'll play around with it and see the setup you want for it - maybe it's a hidden config somewhere